# FFMPEG convert live streaming m3u8 for mpeg-dash

Tags: html, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

How Can I create a gateway from live streaming m3u8 example http://srv6.zoeweb.tv:1935/z330-live/stream/playlist.m3u8 for mpeg-dash with FFMPEG for a player in player hhml5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4Box can be used to generate MP4 segments from MPEG-2 TS HLS files and MPD from M3U8 to be played with DASH.js.